# ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode6, parse-osx-sdk

I am trying to compile my app with Parse OS X SDK (downloaded directly from Parse, not Cocoapods etc.). Initially the build succeeds. Then, after a few tries/few seconds, when I try to build my project again, it fails with "ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h not found" error. It *is* there. I can browse to it in Finder, it is included in the project, and besides all, it just built successfully a few seconds ago!

I clean build folder, remove derived data, restart Xcode, and it compiles again successfully, but after a few seconds, again, it fails with the same error.

What should I do?

It is there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't do "ParseOSX/ParseOSX.h", do this

```
#import "ParseOSX.h"
```

remove the "ParseOSX/"

Comment: Nope. Then it can't find it at all, not even initially.

Comment: That's super weird, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up creating a normal app bundle, but still using just command line with it.